Transferring Data by Parameters to Multiple Target Worksheets
I have a Single Target Worksheet working, but when I add the second target the range says it's nothing, and I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.
Working Code for Single Target
        Sub DealerRules() 'Working
            Dim r As Long, wsTarget As Worksheet, cel As Range

            r = 3
            With ThisWorkbook
                Set wsTarget = .Sheets("LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXT")
                With .ActiveSheet
                    For Each cel In .Range("B3:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
                        If cel.Value = 1 Or cel.Value = 2 Then
                        .Range(cel.Offset(, -1).Address & ":Q" & cel.Row).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("A" & r & ":Q" & r)


                    r = r + 1


                        End If
                    Next

                End With
            End With
        End Sub

Second Target Add Not Working Data To Copy is Empty
        Sub DealerRules()
            Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, wsTarget1 As Worksheet, wsTarget2 As Worksheet, cel As Range, dataToCopy As Variant

            r1 = 3 ' Start from row 3 in the first target sheet
            r2 = 3 ' Start from row 3 in the second target sheet
            With ThisWorkbook
                Set wsTarget1 = .Sheets("LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXT")
                Set wsTarget2 = .Sheets("LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXO")
                With .Sheets("LXXXXXXB RAW") 'Sets the Activesheet
                    For Each cel In .Range("B3:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
                        If Left(cel.Offset(, -1).Value, 5) = "101.18" And (cel.Value = 1 Or cel.Value = 2) Then
                           dataToCopy = .Range(cel.Offset(, -1).Address & ":Q" & cel.Row).Value  'Copy Destination:=wsTarget1.Range("A" & r1 & ":Q" & r1)
                           If Not IsEmpty(dataToCopy) Then
                           wsTarget1.Range("A" & r1 & ":Q" & r1).Value = dataToCopy
                            r1 = r1 + 1
                            End If
                        ElseIf Left(cel.Offset(, -1).Value, 5) = "101.19" And (cel.Value = 1 Or cel.Value = 2) Then
                            dataToCopy = .Range(cel.Offset(, -1).Address & ":Q" & cel.Row).Value  '.Range(cel.Offset(, -1).Address & ":Q" & cel.Row).Copy Destination:=wsTarget2.Range("A" & r2 & ":Q" & r2)
                            If Not IsEmpty(dataToCopy) Then
                            wsTarget2.Range("A" & r2 & ":Q" & r2).Value = dataToCopy
                            r2 = r2 + 1
                        End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End With
            End With
        End Sub

I've tried a lot of different failing methods. I'm hoping someone who speaks VBA Fluently can assist.

In your original code Left(cel.Offset(, -1).Value, 5) = "101.19" will never be TRUE as "101.19" is six characters long and you are only looking at the first five characters.  In future try to step thru your code line by line using the debugger, it helps to catch those simple errors.
Sub DealerRules()
    Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, wsTarget1 As Worksheet, wsTarget2 As Worksheet, cel As Range

    r1 = 3 ' Start from row 3 in the first target sheet
    r2 = 3 ' Start from row 3 in the second target sheet
    
    Set wsTarget1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXT")
    Set wsTarget2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXO")
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LXXXXXXB RAW") ' Active sheet
        For Each cel In .Range("B3:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
            If cel.Value = 1 Or cel.Value = 2 Then
                Select Case Left(cel.Offset(, -1).Value, 6)
                    Case "101.18"
                        CopyData cel, wsTarget1, r1
                        r1 = r1 + 1
                    Case "101.19"
                        CopyData cel, wsTarget2, r2
                        r2 = r2 + 1
                End Select
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub

Sub CopyData(cel As Range, wsTarget As Worksheet, targetRow As Long)
    Dim dataToCopy As Variant
    dataToCopy = cel.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 17).Value ' Copy range from column A to Q
    If Not IsEmpty(dataToCopy) Then
        wsTarget.Range("A" & targetRow & ":Q" & targetRow).Value = dataToCopy
    End If
End Sub


Good catch! The problem with my code was the length of the Cell Data being Six, but checking for Five. The sad part is I've stared at that for two days not seeing it. Thanks for the help!

Copy To Another Worksheet with Multiple Criteria

Main
Sub DealerRulesMulti()
     
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SOURCE_SHEET_NAME As String = "LXXXXXXB RAW"
    Const SOURCE_TOP_LAST_ROW_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B3"
    Const SOURCE_COPY_COLUMNS As String = "A:Q"
    Dim SOURCE_LOOKUP_COLUMNS() As Variant: SOURCE_LOOKUP_COLUMNS = VBA.Array( _
        "B", "A") ' reuqirement 1, requirement 2
    Dim SOURCE_CRITERIA() As Variant: SOURCE_CRITERIA = VBA.Array( _
        "101.18", "101.19") ' corresponding to the values in the target arrays!
    Dim TARGET_SHEET_NAMES() As Variant: TARGET_SHEET_NAMES = VBA.Array( _
        "LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXT", "LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXO")
    Dim TARGET_TOP_CELL_ADDRESSES() As Variant:
    TARGET_TOP_CELL_ADDRESSES = VBA.Array("A3", "A3")
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet and the source single-column range
    ' based on a specific column (cell).
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SOURCE_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = RefSingleColumnRangeEnd(sws, SOURCE_TOP_LAST_ROW_CELL_ADDRESS)
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in the source last row range
    
    ' Return the lookup ranges' references in an array.
    
    Dim sUpper As Long: sUpper = UBound(SOURCE_LOOKUP_COLUMNS)
    Dim slRanges() As Range: ReDim slRanges(0 To sUpper)
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To sUpper
        Set slRanges(i) = srg.EntireRow.Columns(SOURCE_LOOKUP_COLUMNS(i))
    Next i
     
    ' Return the criteria lengths in an array.
     
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(SOURCE_CRITERIA)
    
    Dim cLens() As Long: ReDim cLens(0 To cUpper)
    
    For i = 0 To cUpper
        cLens(i) = Len(SOURCE_CRITERIA(i))
    Next i
    
    ' Reference the copy range.
    
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(SOURCE_COPY_COLUMNS)
    
    ' Combine the rows meeting the requirements into unioned ranges.
    
    Dim suRanges() As Range: ReDim suRanges(0 To sUpper)
    Dim scell As Range, sValue As Variant, sRow As Long, tRowsCount As Long

    For Each scell In slRanges(0).Cells
        sRow = sRow + 1
        If IsRequirementMet1(scell.Value) Then
            sValue = slRanges(1).Rows(sRow).Value
            For i = 0 To cUpper
                If IsRequirementMet2( _
                        sValue, SOURCE_CRITERIA(i), cLens(i)) Then
                    BuildRange suRanges(i), scrg.Rows(sRow)
                    tRowsCount = tRowsCount + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next scell
        
    If tRowsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no rows found
    
    ' Copy the combined (unioned) source rows to the target cells at once.
    
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = scrg.Columns.Count
     
    Dim tws As Worksheet, tcell As Range
    
    For i = 0 To cUpper
        If Not suRanges(i) Is Nothing Then
            ' Reference.
            Set tws = wb.Sheets(TARGET_SHEET_NAMES(i))
            Set tcell = tws.Range(TARGET_TOP_CELL_ADDRESSES(i))
            ' Clear.
            With tcell.Resize(, ColumnsCount)
                .Resize(tws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Clear
            End With
            ' Copy.
            suRanges(i).Copy Destination:=tcell
        End If
    Next i
        
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox tRowsCount & " row" & IIf(tRowsCount = 1, "", "s") & " copied.", _
        vbInformation

End Sub

Help Specific
Function IsRequirementMet1(ByVal Value As Variant) As Boolean
    If Not VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then Exit Function ' is not a number
    Select Case Value
        Case 1, 2: IsRequirementMet1 = True
    End Select
End Function

Function IsRequirementMet2( _
    ByVal Value As Variant, _
    ByVal CriteriaString As String, _
    ByVal CriteriaLength As Long) _
As Boolean
    If Left(CStr(Value), CriteriaLength) <> CriteriaString Then Exit Function
    IsRequirementMet2 = True
End Function

Help Reusable
Sub BuildRange( _
        ByRef builtRange As Range, _
        ByVal addRange As Range)
    If builtRange Is Nothing Then
        Set builtRange = addRange
    Else
        Set builtRange = Union(builtRange, addRange)
    End If
End Sub

Function RefSingleColumnRangeEnd( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal TopCellAddress As String) _
As Range
    
    ' Validate inputs.
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' no worksheet reference
    
    Dim tcell As Range:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set tcell = ws.Range(TopCellAddress)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If tcell Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' invalid address, 'ws' out of scope
    
    ' Attempt to reference the range.
    
    With tcell.Cells(1)
        Dim RowsCount As Long:
        RowsCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If RowsCount < 1 Then Exit Function
        Set RefSingleColumnRangeEnd = .Resize(RowsCount)
    End With

End Function

Main Single

Sub DealerRulesSingle()
     
    ' Define constants.
    Const SOURCE_SHEET_NAME As String = "LXXXXXXB RAW"
    Const SOURCE_TOP_LOOKUP_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B3"
    Const SOURCE_COPY_COLUMNS As String = "A:Q"
    Const TARGET_SHEET_NAME As String = "LXXXXXXB-LXXXXXXT"
    Const TARGET_TOP_LEFT_PASTE_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A3"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source lookup and copy ranges.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SOURCE_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim slrg As Range:
    Set slrg = RefSingleColumnRangeEnd(sws, SOURCE_TOP_LOOKUP_CELL_ADDRESS)
    If slrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in the source lookup range
    
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(SOURCE_COPY_COLUMNS)
    
    ' Combine the rows meeting the requirement into a unioned range.
    
    Dim surg As Range, scell As Range, sRow As Long, tRowsCount As Long

    For Each scell In slrg.Cells
        sRow = sRow + 1
        If IsRequirementMet1(scell.Value) Then
            tRowsCount = tRowsCount + 1
            BuildRange surg, scrg.Rows(sRow)
        End If
    Next scell
        
    If tRowsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub  ' no rows found
    
    ' Reference the top target cell.
    
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets(TARGET_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim tcell As Range:
    Set tcell = tws.Range(TARGET_TOP_LEFT_PASTE_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Copy the combined (unioned) source rows to the target cell at once.
    
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = scrg.Columns.Count
     
    ' Clear.
    With tcell.Resize(, ColumnsCount)
        .Resize(tws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Clear
    End With
    
    ' Copy.
    surg.Copy Destination:=tcell
        
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox tRowsCount & " row" & IIf(tRowsCount = 1, "", "s") & " copied.", _
        vbInformation

End Sub


Good catch! The problem with my code was the length of the Cell Data being Six, but checking for Five. The sad part is I've stared at that for two days not seeing it. Thanks for the help!
